# What are the differences in the configuration of the network on Proxmox (KVM)?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, proxmox, configuration

I have a dedicated server, one main public IP from /27 and two single public IPs also from the same /27 (I think the provider manages single IPs using the VLAN tags).

I want to have a KVM running on the server and two VMs on the KVM. I would like not to use NAT or Bridge model, but setting a KVM Host as router, so I can access the VMs from the Internet.

It should look like here:

[image: Hetzner's Routing mode for KVM]

I found two different tutorials one saying

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet !!manual!!

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address x.x.x.x
  pointtopoint x.x.x.1
  gw x.x.x.1
  bridge_ports !!eth0!!
  ...
```

and another saying:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet !!static!!
  address x.x.x.x
  pointtopoint x.x.x.1
  gw x.x.x.1

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address x.x.x.x
  pointtopoint x.x.x.1
  gw x.x.x.1
  bridge_ports !!none!!
  ...
```

It is very confusing, considering that none of them working.

What are the differences of combining **manual with bridge_ports eth0** and **static with bridge_ports none**?

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a bridge, you will be able to access the VMs from the internet, by their public IPs.

Comment: I thought it will simple work, but it doesn't: here is more infromation. [http://serverfault.com/questions/523729/why-vm-cannot-get-the-public-ip-i-have-from-provider]

The arp and ip tables are empty, even the /etc/network/interfaces is configured